# Checkbox data saved in db as "on" in PHP, Mysqli

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, mysqli, php-7

Error :- Checkbox data saved in db as "on" - used explode, implode, in_array so problem in fetching checkbox db data for updating.-----
Data retrieve function to show dynamic checkbox as well as retrive data to again update

html----

```
<th>Qualification</th>
            <td> <div style="height:50; overflow:scroll">
            <?php echo get_checkbox_list("qualification","qualification_id","qualification_name","st_qul[]",$data[$col_id]);?>
            </div></td>

    function get_checkbox_list($table,$col_id,$col_value,$name,$sel=0)
    {
        global $con;
         $query= "SELECT * from $table";
         $rs=mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error("error"));
         $optionlist="";
         $sel=explode(",", $sel);

         while ($data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs))
          {


            if (in_array($data[$col_id], $sel)) {

                    $optionlist.="<input type=checkbox name=$name id=$data[$col_id] checked> $data[$col_value] <br>";
                }
                else{
                                    $optionlist.="<input type=checkbox name=$name id=$data[$col_id]> $data[$col_value] <br>";  
                }
         }
         return $optionlist;
    }
```

PHP: Save and update mysqli query-----

```
function save_student()
{
    global $con;
    $_REQUEST['st_qul']=implode(",",$_REQUEST['st_qul']);
    $img_name=$_FILES[st_photo][name];
    if ($img_name) 
    {
        $img_location=$_FILES[st_photo][tmp_name];
        $img_arr=explode(".",$img_name );
        $img_name=$img_arr[0]."_".time().".".$img_arr[1];
        move_uploaded_file($img_location, "../uploads/$img_name");
    }
    else
    {
    $img_name=$_REQUEST[st_photo];
    }
if ($_REQUEST['st_id'])
{
    $query="UPDATE `student_add` SET `st_name` = '".$_REQUEST['st_name']."',
    `st_father` = '".$_REQUEST['st_father']."', `st_add1` = '".$_REQUEST['st_add1']."',
    `st_add2` = '".$_REQUEST['st_add2']."', `st_city` = '".$_REQUEST['st_city']."',
    `st_state` = '".$_REQUEST['st_state']."',`st_country` = '".$_REQUEST['st_country']."',
                `st_nat` = '".$_REQUEST['st_nat']."', `st_gender` = '".$_REQUEST['st_gender']."',
                `st_qul` = '".$_REQUEST['st_qul']."', `st_course` = '".$_REQUEST['st_course']."',
                `st_photo` = '$img_name',`st_hobbies` = '".$_REQUEST['st_hobbies']."',
                `st_mobile` = '".$_REQUEST['st_mobile']."'
                WHERE `st_id` = $_REQUEST[st_id];";

                $msg="Data Updated Successfully..";
}
else{
        $query="INSERT INTO `student_add` (`st_name`, `st_father`, `st_add1`, `st_add2`, `st_city`, `st_state`, `st_country`, `st_nat`, `st_gender`, `st_qul`, `st_course`, `st_photo`, `st_hobbies`, `st_mobile`) VALUES ('".$_REQUEST['st_name']."', '".$_REQUEST['st_father']."', '".$_REQUEST['st_add1']."', '".$_REQUEST['st_add2']."', '".$_REQUEST['st_city']."', '".$_REQUEST['st_state']."', '".$_REQUEST['st_country']."', '".$_REQUEST['st_nat']."', '".$_REQUEST['st_gender']."', '".$_REQUEST['st_qul']."', '".$_REQUEST['st_course']."', '$img_name', '".$_REQUEST['st_hobbies']."', '".$_REQUEST['st_mobile']."');";

        $msg="Data Saved Successfully..";
}
    $rs=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    if ($rs)
     {
        header("Location:../student_view.php?msg=$msg");
     }
}
```

[image: stored checkbox value]

Comment: Set value of checkbox  1 as value="1".

Comment: Also show me the HTML code.

Comment: You are open to SQL injections, use parameterized queries. Also please refer to http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php, the first parameter of that function is not take a string to output.

Comment: Please format the question as it should be formatted, that image is not useable in its current format.

Comment: This needs to have a clear question.  It's hard to say it's been answered if we don't know what it is asking.

Comment: @KamranJabbar   HTML CODE---   <th>Qualification</th>
   <td> <div style="height:30; overflow:scroll;">
   <?php echo get_checkbox_list("qualification","qualification_id","qualification_name","st_qul[]",$data[$col_id]);?>
   </div></td>
  </tr>

Comment: @KamranJabbar  
SQL----SQL Query:---------##### $_REQUEST['st_qul']=implode(",",$_REQUEST['st_qul']); $query="INSERT INTO `student_add` ( `st_qul`) VALUES ('".$_REQUEST['st_qul']."');"; $rs=mysqli_query($con,$query); if ($rs) { header("Location:../student_view.php?msg=$msg"); }

Comment: @KamranJabbar-### Function dynamic checkbox list function get_checkbox_list($table,$col_id,$col_value,$name,$sel=0) {global $con; $query= "SELECT * from $table"; $rs=mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error("error")); $optionlist="";$sel=explode(",", $sel); while ($data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) { if (in_array($data[$col_id], $sel)) { $optionlist.="<input type=checkbox name=$name id=$data[$col_id] checked> $data[$col_value] <br>"; }else{ $optionlist.="<input type=checkbox name=$name id=$data[$col_id]> $data[$col_value] <br>"; }} return $optionlist; }

Comment: @KamranJabbar
## call dynamic generating checkbox <?php echo get_checkbox_list("qualification","qualification_id","qualification_name","st_qul[]",$data[$col_id]);?></div></td></tr>

Answer (score 0):

Set the "Value"-attribue

```
<input type="checkbox" name"foo" value="1"> // or whatever Value you like
```

On POST, "foo" will supply "1", if foo is checked.

Comment: Kindly see my all comments.